# Keep/select columns with the n highest values in last row of a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataframe as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 3, 6], [7, 2, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

df
```

Output:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 | 6 |
| 7 | 2 | 9 |

I want to select or keep the two columns, with the highest values in the last row. What is the best way to approach?
So in fact I just want to select or keep column 'a' due to value 7 and column 'c' due to value 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
df = df[df.iloc[-1].nlargest(2).index]
```

Output:

```
   c  a
0  3  1
1  6  4
2  9  7
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep original column sequence as well, you can use [`Index.intersection()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) together with [`.nlargest()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html), as follows:

```
df[df.columns.intersection(df.iloc[-1].nlargest(2).index, sort=False)]
```

Result:

```
   a  c
0  1  3
1  4  6
2  7  9
```